# creating jar file and runing in command prompt window

Tags: java, jar

I have created several jar files and run them in cmd but recently I cant create new ones...in fact, I make a jar file but as I run it in cmd the following error message appears;

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Sun.launcher.launcherhelper.getMainClassFromJar(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You need to give more detail - how did you create the jar file, what does the manifest look like, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar has to define the main class in it's manifest if you want to start with just `java -jar myjar.jar`, otherwise you will need to start with `java -cp myjar.jar com.example.Mainclass`.

Comment: TNX, I got what was wrong in exporting a jar file.....I didn't introduce the main class and I just clicked the finish button in the first step.